# Standing/Sitting on Motzei Shabbat for Vihi Noam and Uva LeTzion

Tags: minhag, tefilla, standing-sitting, motzei-shabbos

I have noticed that some people are particular to stand on Motzei Shabbat for Vihi Noam and Uva LeTzion, whereas others are particular to sit.

- Is this really something significant?
- Whose opinion is it that a person should stand, and which groups (typically) follow that opinion?
- Whose opinion is it that a person should sit, and which groups (typically) follow that opinion?

Comment: One possibility: Those who are particular to stand are particular because it's more comfortable for them, likewise for those who are particular to sit. It may be worth asking them.

Comment: I'll see what I can find further. My assumption for those who stand - it followed Kaddish, and another one immediately follows these paragraphs. Another possibility - some stand for "Uval Letziyon" b/c it's considered like "kedusha" (these same people also stand when said during weekday Shacharit, I believe.)

Comment: My father's minhag is to stand for *Vihi Noam* and sit for *V'ata Kadosh*. I've noticed other people in shul doing this as well, so that seems to be another option.

Answer (score 2):

See [Kaf Hachaim 295/1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14421&st=&pgnum=168) who states that one should say the full paragraph of *V'yehi No'am* or at least the 1st verse should be said while standing.

> והמעם הוא כי
>    הכוונה עתה לקבל אור החוזר מן הבינה הנקראת נועס ה׳ מסוד תוספת שבת ולכן
>   צריך שיהיה מעומד ועי״ש

I have no idea what he means by אור החוזר מן הבינה . It sounds like a Kabbalistic term. If someone knows what this means, feel free to edit this into my answer.

I haven't found a reason why the 2nd paragraph, *Ve'Atah Kadosh* is said standing (if it is at all). My own sense / opinion - it should be said sitting because the beginning verse says **יושב** תהלות ישראל . But then again, the beginning of *Veyehi No'am"* also says **יושב** בסתר עליון - Just my thoughts on these two.

Comment: See [Ben Ish Chai, Vayetze 2nd year](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14054&st=&pgnum=283&hilite=).

Comment: About the kdusha, probably it is similiar to [Kdusha d'sidra of shcharit, 2nd note](http://ph.yhb.org.il/02-23-02/)
So - Sit/Kabalistic/Sfradim

Comment: אור חוזר is a Kabbalistic term. It literally means reflected light. Conceptually it is like the statement in Avos that a teacher learns the most from his students. Bina is one of the 10 Sefiros.

Comment: All of that is a reference to drawing the holiness of Shabbos into the coming week and into day to day life.

Answer (score 1):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן צו - דיני תפלת ערבית ודיני הבדלה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0095_L2) says:

> אַחַר כָּךְ אוֹמְרִים וִיהִי נֹעַם, לְפִי שֶׁהוּא מִזְמוֹר שֶׁל בְּרָכָה, שֶׁבּוֹ בֵּרַךְ מֹשֶׁה אֶת יִשְֹרָאֵל בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁסִּיְמוּ מְלֶאכֶת הַמִּשְׁכָּן. **וְיֵשׁ לְאָמְרוֹ מְעֻמָּד**.‏

His source is possible the  באר היטב in Shulchan Aruch [סימן רצה - הבדלה שעושה שליח צבור](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_25.html#HtmpReportNum0053_L2) who says:

> ויהי נועם. **וצריך לאומרו מעומד** כתבים.‏

Note that:

- His source is כתבים - that's how he referred to the writings of the Talmidei HaAri z"l
- It's not a Mechaber, but the Remo.

The ArtScroll Siddur says (IIRC) that one only need stand for the first verse.